# Set Post Thumbnails in Percents

Tags: post-thumbnails, responsive

I've built this responsive site on WordPress and got a little curious as to how I can set the post thumbnails in percentages. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, images must have real absolute sizes :)

A post thumbnail is essentially a different sized version of the image. While you can calculate how much for example 70% of 1024 is, and genereate a ~700px wide image, you cannot do this for each of your visitors. It would kill your host's CPU...

The closest thing you can do is to browser-resize images to fit their container:

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, I was just really curious to see if that could be done with WordPress or not. Thanks for confirming this for me :)

Answer (score 0):

*Follow up to @OneTrickPony A:*

You could also use a background image, resize the container accordingly and then add [`background-size: contain;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341358/set-size-on-background-image-with-css/9722597#9722597).

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that but I wanted to see if doing it this way would possible.